# Why does dispatch_get_specific not recognize the queue I created?

Tags: ios

I created a serial queue and set the ID to the queue with dispatch_queue_set_specific, but calling this queue in other classes, I cannot use the dispatch_get_specific test to enter the if statement.

here is my create code:

```
+ (dispatch_queue_t)sharedFollowerQueue
{
    return [[self shareInstance] contextQueue];
}

- (dispatch_queue_t)contextQueue
{
    static dispatch_queue_t sharedFollowerQueue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedFollowerQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.weuseSoftware.Instracker.UserManageTool.followerQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        dispatch_queue_set_specific(sharedFollowerQueue, sharedFollowerQueueKey, (__bridge void *)self, NULL);
    });
    return sharedFollowerQueue;
}
```

here is my calling code,but I can't enter the if statement

```
- (void)queryForADayFollowersCountWithCallBack:(void (^)(NSArray <GraphEntity *> *))callBack
{
    dispatch_queue_t queue = [[self class] sharedFollowerQueue];
    NSMutableArray *graphArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        if (dispatch_get_specific(sharedFollowerQueueKey)) {
            NSLog(@"----get in----");
            RLMArray *currentDayUsers = [self currentDayUsers];
            if (currentDayUsers.count == 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < currentDayUsers.count; i++) {
                MainUser *user = currentDayUsers[i];
                GraphEntity *gEntity = [[GraphEntity alloc] init];
                gEntity.userDate = user.createDate;
                gEntity.number = user.user.followed_by_count.integerValue;
                [graphArray addObject:gEntity];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                if (callBack) {
                    callBack([graphArray copy]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I create my key

```
static const void* const sharedFollowerQueueKey = &sharedFollowerQueueKey;
```

when I log key in create code, I got the key adress

```
(lldb) po sharedFollowerQueueKey
0x00000001032c41d0
```

then in my calling code,I got the key adress

```
    (lldb) po sharedFollowerQueueKey
0x00000001032c33e8
```

why they are different?

Comment: Please don't post images of code; post the actual code.

Comment: someone edit your question please approve if it is valid and provide code

Comment: thankyou,I've post the actual code instead of images